# Hotspot Network has no internet connection after upgrade to Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: networking, upgrade, network-manager, 17.04, ap-hotspot

I just upgraded my system to Ubuntu 17.04 from 16.10. Before the upgrade, the hotspot was doing great, but after the upgrade, I cannot connect to the internet from my phone. I can setup the hotspot network, but it doesn't connect to the internet. What should I do?

Comment: Same here, plus a few other glitches...